# Sign conventions pressure volume work

Tags: thermodynamics, work, conventions

In the first law of thermodynamics, using the convention that work is done on the system by the surroundings,
$dU=Q+W$.

Usually it is written that pressure volume work is $W=-pdV$, where $p$ is external pressure on the system boundary and $dV$ is the change in volume of the system, so $dU=Q-pdV$.

I just wanted to double check with you that the (to me somewhat confusing) sign convention used for $p$ in this case, is that it is negative if the force is pointing in the same direction as the surface normal ("pulling" on the system) and positive if the force is pointing into the system ("pushing" the system).

So for a force that pulls on the system, say e.g. $p=-3N/m^2$, we have $dU=Q-(-3N/m^2)dV$.

Answer (score 0):

To simplify matters make $Q=0$ so $dU=-P\,dV$ and $-P\,dV$ is the work done **on** the system by external forces.
The $P\,dV$ comes from the **force** exerted on a piston of area $A$ by a gas at pressure $P$ is $PA$ and so the external **force** must be $PA$ in the opposite direction.
Then work done by the external force on the gas is $PA$ times the displacement of the piston.

Pressure is a scalar quantity and hence does not have a direction.

$dV = V_{\rm final} -V_{\rm initial}$ and if $V_{\rm final} <V_{\rm initial}$, ie the gas is compressed, then $dV$ is negative and so $-P\,dV$ is positive, (external force and displacement in the same direction), thus work is done on the gas and its internal energy increases.

In terms of what you have written, ask yourself the question, "how you would obtain a negative pressure, ie a pressure lower than $0\,\rm Pa$?"

---

The Wikipedia article on [pressure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pressure#Formula) contains the following passage:

> Pressure is a **scalar** quantity. It relates the vector area element (a
> vector normal to the surface) with the normal force acting on it. The
> pressure is the scalar proportionality constant that relates the two
> normal vectors:
>
> $$d{\bf F}_n = -P\,d{\bf A} = -P\,{\bf n}\,dA$$
>
> The minus sign comes from the convention that the force is considered
> towards the surface element, while the normal vector points outward.
> The equation has meaning in that, for any surface $S$ in contact with
> the fluid, the total force exerted by the fluid on that surface is the
> surface integral over S of the right-hand side of the above equation.
>
> It is incorrect (although rather usual) to say "the pressure is
> directed in such or such direction". The pressure, as a **scalar**,
> has no direction. The force given by the previous relationship to the
> quantity has a direction, but the pressure does not. If we change the
> orientation of the surface element, the direction of the normal force
> changes accordingly, but the pressure remains the same.

The last sentence is a good illustration of the fact that pressure has no direction.

[image]

The force on piston due to the gas is equal in magnitude to the external force on the piston.

If the volume of the **gas** (system) decreases then $dV$ is negative and positive work is done on the gas by the external force.

Comment: Your answer does not mention what direction the force exerted on the piston of area A has. It can either be directed along the surface nornal, or in the opposite direction (i.e. into the body). So your answer avoids the question I posed. (You are not alone, every thermodynamics text I have ever seen avoids this question)

Comment: Pressure does not seem to be the magnitude of the force, but it seems to be the negative of the dot product of the force times the directional surface element $p=-\langle F, dA\rangle$, but I have not found why this weird convention seem to be used (i.e. why not $\langle F, dA\rangle$). I disagree that it does not have a direction. It is only a scalar up to a sign determined by the orientation of the system and what convention you use.

Comment: I do not know why you assume that pressure is negative when the volume shrinks. But from my understanding of the sign convention, that means it shrinks when the force points out of the body (i.e. pulled), which seems like an odd situation (maybe it is in vacuum?).

Comment: @Emil in your last comment you write that I assumed pressure to be negative.  This is not so.  It is the change in volume of the system which is negative which with the other negative already present makes $-P dV$, the external work done on the system a positive quantity.

Comment: You wrote $pdV$ was positive, then you have a mistake in your text. (if dV is negative, p has to be negative, if pdV is positive)

Comment: @Emil I have corrected my mistake. Thank you for pointing it out.  I have also added to my answer to emphasis that pressure does not have a direction.

Comment: I had read wikipedia but it was confusing to me -- what is meant with a force "considered" to be in a direction? A force already has a direction. So I think what is actually happening is that there is a sign convention on p. If we skip p altogether I think $W=\langle F , dA\rangle$ which has no weird minuses at all, very easy to understand.

Answer (score 0):

> In the first law of thermodynamics, using the convention that work is
> done on the system by the surroundings, $dU=Q+W$.

That is the version typically used in chemistry and should read $\Delta U=Q+W$. The differential form is $dU=\delta Q+\delta W$ where here $\delta Q$ and $\delta W$ are inexact differentials. In physics and engineering it is typically $\Delta U=Q-W$.

> Usually it is written that pressure volume work is $W=-pdV$, where $p$
> is external pressure on the system boundary and $dV$ is the change in
> volume of the system, so $dU=Q-pdV$.

This is the work done by the surroundings on the system and is $W$ in the $\Delta U=Q+W$ version of the first law. It is positive when the direction of the external force exerted by the surroundings is the same as the direction of the displacement $dV$ of the system caused by the force, i.e, when $dV\lt 0$. When something does positive work it transfers energy to something. In this case, energy is transferred from the surroundings to the system.

The work done by the system on the surroundings, which is $W$ in the $\Delta U=Q-W$ version of the first law, is the negative of the work done by the surroundings on the system, or $dW=pdV$ where $p$ is now the pressure of the system. If $dV\lt 0$ (compression work) the force exerted by system is opposite in direction to the displacement $dV$ of the system giving negative work. When something does negative work it takes energy from something else. In this case, by doing negative work the system takes energy from the surroundings. In the $\Delta U=Q-W$ this again results in an increase in internal energy, making the two versions of the first law consistent.

In summary $W$ is the work done by the system on the surroundings in the $\Delta U=Q-W$ version of the first law and  $W$ is the work done by the surroundings on the system in the $\Delta U=Q+W$ version of the first law. Each is the negative of the other.

Hope this helps.